# jquery doesn't append but replaces contents of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to append a set of html codes to div but won't work. I've already tried other solutions posted here in stackoverflow but still won't work.

```
var placeholder = $('<div class="view view-first img" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;" title="Upload Car Image">' +
                            '<input type="hidden" value="" class="photodata photoguid" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" value="" class="photoid" />' +
                            '<img src="" style="height: 200px; width: 250px;" class="thumbnailPreview" />' +
                            '<div class="mask">' +
                                '<button type="button" class="info btn btn-primary profilepic" style="display: none;" title="Active display photo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span></button>' +
                                '<button type="button" class="info btn btn-danger deletephoto" style="margin-left: 5px; display: none;" title="Delete Photo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>');

$.ajax({
            url: $("#saveImageGuid").val(),
            type: "post",
            data: '{ recordID: "' + $(".recordID").val() + '", photoguid: "' + fileGroupInfo.uuid + '"}',
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".uploadcontainer").find("#alertmessage").remove();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alertmessage.attr("class", "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible");
                alertmessage.find("#message").text(data.status);
                $(".uploadcontainer").append(alertmessage);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.statusCode == 500)
                {
                    alertmessage.attr("class", "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible");
                }
                else
                {
                    alertmessage.attr("class", "alert alert-success alert-dismissible");

                    var guids = jQuery.parseJSON(data.guids);
                    var thumbnails;

                    $.each($(guids), function (key, value) {
                        var uploadcaregeturl = "@Config.UploadCareGETUrl";
                        uploadcaregeturl = uploadcaregeturl.replace("{0}", value);

                        placeholder.find(".thumbnailPreview").attr("src", uploadcaregeturl);

                        $(".thumbnailcontainer").append(placeholder);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm getting a list from controller then place it inside the img src attribute, then append it to div. After executing the loop in success portion of ajax, it doesn't append every placeholder but instead replaces what was appended at previous loop. Any ideas where I went wrong.

Comment: Try creating a http://jsfiddle.net to help us visualise your problem.

Comment: Your success callback will not get called when you get a 500 error, your error callback will instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now. I placed the placeholder inside the success portion and also restructure my codes in controller for better handling of statuscodes.

```
$.ajax({
        url: $("#saveImageGuid").val(),
        type: "post",
        data: '{ recordID: "' + $(".recordID").val() + '", photoguid: "' + fileGroupInfo.uuid + '"}',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".uploadcontainer").find("#alertmessage").remove();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alertmessage.attr("class", "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible");
            alertmessage.find("#message").text(data.status);
            $(".uploadcontainer").append(alertmessage);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alertmessage.attr("class", "alert alert-success alert-dismissible");

            var guids = jQuery.parseJSON(data.guids);
            var thumbnails;

            $.each($(guids), function (key, value) {
                var placeholder = $('<div class="view view-first img...');

                var uploadcaregeturl = "@Config.UploadCareGETUrl";
                uploadcaregeturl = uploadcaregeturl.replace("{0}", value);

                placeholder.find(".thumbnailPreview").attr("src", uploadcaregeturl);

                $(".thumbnailcontainer").append(placeholder);
            });
         }
    });
```